# Add Items to Array In C#

Tags: c#, arrays

I have a shopping cart that I iterate through in a foreach loop. Each Item in the cart needs to be added to an orderItemList array.

```
orderItemList = 
[{
orderItemId = 1,
quantity = 2
},{
orderItemId = 2, 
quantity =1 
}]
```

So I was trying to use

```
foreach(var items in shoppingCart)
{
var newOrderItems = new[] 
{  new orderItem { orderItemId = item.Id , quantity = item.quantity }
};
```

It is only adding the last item in the cart. It loops through and creates each one but only the last one is added. What am i missing?

newOrderItems only returns the one item even though it loops.

Comment: You're creating a new array in every iteration..?

Comment: That's what its looking like but what i need to do is add to the array a new item.

Comment: I need multiple items in the one array.

Comment: arrays are fixed sized, you can't add to or remove an item from an array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each time in the loop you're creating a new array (hence the "new[]") with one item in it.  An array's size cannot be changed so instead use a List<> object:

```
newOrderItems = new List<orderItem>();
foreach(var items in shoppingCart)
{
  newOrderItems.Add(new orderItem { orderItemId = item.Id , quantity =   item.quantity});
};
```

A List<> can be treated like an array for almost all purposes.  If you NEED an array than you can easily convert it ...

```
var newOrderItemsArray = newOrderItems.ToArray();
```

Comment: I can't see why this is the accepted answer as it does not answer the question. The question is about adding items to array not a list and also not converting a list into an array

Comment: He's creating a new array each time through the loop, not adding an item to an existing array.  In fact you can't add to an array so I suggested using a List<> instead

Answer (score 1):

Just declare your array outside the loop...here's an example using arrays:

```
OrderItem[] newOrderItems = new OrderItem[shoppingCart.Length];

for (int i = 0; i < shoppingCart.Length; i++)
{
    var item = shoppingCart[i];
    newOrderItems[i] = new OrderItem {orderItemId = item.Id, quantity = item.quantity};
}
```

There are other examples using `List` objects, but I think this is the coolest one-line way to convert all your shopping cart items into a `List` of `OrderItem` objects:

```
List<OrderItem> newOrderItems = shoppingCart.Select(item =>
    new OrderItem {orderItemId = item.Id, quantity = item.quantity}).ToList();
```

Comment: You're creating a list, not an array.

Comment: I'm always rather uncomfortable calling Linq statements "one-line" when they are really just a long chain of commands.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than using an array, consider using one of the generic collection classes provided by the framework instead. These are designed to be added to and removed from (among many other things. For example:

```
var orderItems = new List<orderItem>();

foreach(var items in shoppingCart)
{
    orderItems.Add(new orderItem 
    {
        orderItemId = item.Id, 
        quantity = item.quantity 
    });
};
```

You could even do this with Linq and eliminate the `foreach`:

```
var orderItems = shoppingCart
    .Select(s => new orderItem
    {
        orderItemId = item.Id, 
        quantity = item.quantity 
    })
    .ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to declare `var newOrderItems = new List<orderItem>();` outside your foreach loop and then use

```
newOrderItems.Add(new orderItem {...});
```

If you declare it inside, it will be created again and again.

Comment: Arrays do not have an Add method.  Your answer will not work

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
for(var item in shoppingCart){
    var newOrderItems = new[] {  new orderItem { orderItemId = item.Id , quantity = item.quantity }};
    orderItemList = orderItemList.Concat(newOrderItems).ToArray();
}
```

Didn't get to test it but it should work.

Comment: Why the downvote? You just had to point that out. Fixed that though.

Comment: because it doesn't compile. improper `for` syntax, `item` is not defined (it is now, though), `order` is not defined, etc...